# page is getting refress after uploading a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to upload a file using ajax function and the file is getting uploaded but the problem is after few time my page is getting refresh so my all the data has gone.
Please help me to prevent the page from the load.

My HTML code is:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="upl" id="upl" /><br />     
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<p id="res"></p>
```

My js file code is:

```
$("#upl").on('change',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0]; 
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response){
            $("#res").append(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
            if(php_script_response){
            return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and my php file code is:

```
<?php

if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
   if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']) ){
   echo "uploaded";
   }
   else{
   echo "not uploaded";
   }
}

?>
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Remove this Submit , as it not required to you and change fort with this  <form action='javascript:void(0)'> and try

Comment: set a return false in you submit button or inside the function in which you are firing your submit event

Comment: `form` should always have `action` and `method` attributes set, even though sometimes `action` would be left empty.

Answer (score 0):

because you havent added action to your form and you want to use ajax then no need of form.

Comment: thank you for your instant reply it works. i change some code according to your suggestion in HTML <form action="upload.php"> and in jquery file var action= $('form').attr('action'); and  url: action  now its working. thank you so much for you solution. :)